# How to debug Composition API in Vue.js 3?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I have just started using Vue.js 3 and am trying to rewrite a component in Composition API.

When I visit the component on the website, it does not render but some API calls are made successfully. I want to debug it so I can see what it holds so far but the browser console shows no errors and `vue dev-tools` lets me drill down to the component but does not show what data is held in the `ref()` variables  (which were previously in `data()` using Options API).

How can I see what each of the `ref` variables hold and see what is happening inside the `setup()` method?

Comment: I've implemented something using a `watch` on a `ref` and `reactive` that does a console log, you can probably do something similar. Watch how you log the vars though, if you log the Proxy itself, it will remain reactive and give you incorrect info. If you're using it across a bigger application, it might be better to use vuex that handles debugging way better.

Comment: Do you use the [Vue.js devtools beta version](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vuejs-devtools/ljjemllljcmogpfapbkkighbhhppjdbg?hl=en)? Otherwise I can only suggest classic `console.log`. A combination between direct logging, the watch and computed property to use as logging makes the dev tools obsolete for normal development. only with vuex you have of course the time travel in the devtools.

Comment: @wittgenstein I just installed the latest beta version on Firefox and it works (shows `ref` values etc)! It wasn't working on Chrome until now. Guess I needed to update thats all.